# why my code get that TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str in Python

Tags: python

```
kmeans_99 = KMeans(n_clusters = 3).fit(X_99)
print(kmeans_99)
labels_99 = kmeans_99.labels_
#Counting the number of the labels in each cluster and saving the data into clustering_classes
clustering_classes_99 = {
 0: [0,0,0],
 1: [0,0,0],
 2: [0,0,0]
}



for i in range(len(y)):
  clustering_classes_99[labels_99[i]][y[i]]     #why this line get error

#Finding the most appeared label in each cluster and computing the purity score

purity_score_99 = (max(clustering_classes_99[0])+max(clustering_classes_99[1])+max(clustering_classes_99[2]))/len(y)
print(f"The purity score is {round(purity_score_99*100,2)} %")
```

I get TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. I can't find the solution. I try lot of ways.

This is the error I got:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-95be616a06bd> in <module>()
     12 
     13 for i in range(len(y)):
---> 14   clustering_classes_99[labels_99[i]][y[i]]
     15 
     16 #Finding the most appeared label in each cluster and computing the purity score

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

please help me to solve this

Comment: There is a list, and there is a string. You're using the string as an index for the list. That's not possible.

Comment: I believe `labels_99[i]` contains strings (labels) in `clustering_classes_99[labels_99[i]][y[i]]`

Comment: Please post the full error message and a _minimal_ example reproducing the error.

Comment: I add the full error @erikced

Comment: if you don't mind can you tell me how to solve it @ElliottFrisch

Comment: What was preventing you from solving this? Did you identify what is the list, and what is the string? Which of them did you expect to be something different, than the string, or the list, respectively?

Comment: Solve what exactly? `for i in range(len(clustering_classes_99)): for j in range(len(clustering_classes_99[i])): print(clustering_classes_99[i][j])`